# ansible doesn't work anymore if I use "RequestTTY force" and "RemoteCommand" in my ssh config

Tags: ssh, ansible

So my ssh config looks like this:

```
Host bastion
    Hostname 35.46.192.2
    User bob2
    RequestTTY force
    RemoteCommand ssh 35.45.96.47
```

So the idea is that I would like to ssh to my `bastion`, then from `bastion` ssh to another server, let's call it `test-vm`, then let `ansible` execute whatever it wants.

Is it possible to make the above work? The error I get says that it cannot ssh due to the host being unreachable when I execute an ansible playbook with the hostname set to `bastion`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but my guess here is that Ansible really wants separate standard output and standard error streams, and using a TTY doesn't produce that (all output goes to the same stream).

In general, if your version of OpenSSH supports it, you're better off using the `ProxyJump` option to SSH through your bastion, since this handles all the connections for you and results in a clean, fully-functional connection.